# a for() loop to compare 2 arrays, and then change another array. JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, compare

I hope someone can help me with this.

I have 2 equal length arrays, and I want to compare them, string by string.
if `array[3]` equals `otherArray[3]`, I want to change the value of yet `anotherArray[3]`

I tried to do this with this code, but for some reason it doesnt change the 3th array, and my console doesnt give any errors.

**Here is the code:**

```
for (i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] === otherArray[i]) {
        targetArray[i] = "string";
    }
}
```

It should be pretty straight forward, but unfortunatly I cant get it to work.
And please no JQuery or other plugins.
Thank you.

Comment: First, your assignment is wrong. `i = (array.length - 1)`

Comment: Other than starting outside the array it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kc1wj7ho/ You'll have to show an example that replicates your problem.

Comment: Also you are not doing element 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === otherArray[i]) {
        targetArray[i] = "string";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
for (i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (j = otherArray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (array[i] === otherArray[j]) {
      targetArray[i] = "string";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct. Just a small change is required

```
for (i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] === otherArray[i]) {
        targetArray[i] = "string";
    } else {
    targetArray[i] = "";
    }
}
```

You have to make null the array values which are not equal, otherwise it will give an undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked! I didnt know that it is required to add a value to the array. My console didnt give any errors. The array I was trying to add the strings to just stayed at the old values.

Answer (score -1):

Is it safer to implement like this if you don't know array index

```
for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i] === otherArray[i]) {
        targetArray[i] = "string";
    }
}
```